# how to apply masking in asp.net (in the HTML 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

how to apply masking in asp.net (in the HTML 5). I intend to mask text fields in custom format

I have tried

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="txt_phoneno">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("document").ready(function () { 
// digit 9 is for number.
 $('#txt_phoneno').('99999-9999999-9'); // like 12345-1234567-1
   });
   </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Valid `Javascript` libraries and call its function. hopefully it will work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>
```

in this libraries the mask function will work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("document").ready(function () { 
// digit 9 is for number.
 $('#txt_phoneno').mask('99999-9999999-9'); // like 12345-1234567-1
   });
   </script>
```